# mobile web site, background does not scale

Tags: css, mobile, background

I have this website (www.dragonit.ca) that when you view it from a mobile device, the background continues to the right for a fair piece.

How can I make it so the background scales to the site and not this huge size that requires you to scroll around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-size:100%;`

Let me know if it works

Comment: I am sorry to report that it does not seem to do anything. :(